# transactions are not working with session factory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an existing code which is written using Spring + Hibernate session factory. I have DAOs written using sessionFactory which are transactional.

```
@Transactional
public class WorkingDAO<T> {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void save(T t){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(t);
    }

}
```

I have unit tests which tests for this DAO which were working fine. Now i want to use Spring JPA so to reduce the effort of writing DAO classes. So I used the following configuration

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
....
</bean>

<bean id="SessionFactory" factory-bean="entityManagerFactory"
      factory-method="getSessionFactory" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
     </bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

However my older unit tests are failing after using the above configuration. Can i use the existing SessionFactory ? or do i have to migrate to the entityManager ?

Comment: Use the correct transaction manager you need to use the `JpaTransactionManager`. Also instead of using the factory method I suggest using the `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` instead.

Comment: How is it failing?  Is there a stack trace you can post?

Comment: How is your DAO configured in the Spring context?  I don't see any component scanning in the Spring config.

Comment: sorry i omitted some configuration related to component scan.  @Deinum i guess HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean is what i need. i will try with his and see if that works.